# Do you need a license to develop a windows phone and blackberry application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, blackberry

Do I need to pay for a license to be able to debug an application **on the device** on these 2 types of phones?

I only own an iOS license which someone needs to have to be able to debug on the phone and not only in the simulator.

What about Windows Phone and blackberry? And if I am able to debug/develop on the phone without a license, would I be able to test push notification, which in the end is what I want to do?

Comment: What the hell will? Why on earth is it off topic? I am googling for half an hour for the answer without any luck , and i should had one 2 hours ago..

Comment: Yes for Windows Phone, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx): "Before you can deploy apps to your Windows Phone, you have to register the phone for development", with one of the prerequisites listed as "A valid and current developer account on Windows Phone Dev Center", joining is $99/yr.

Comment: On BlackBerry you would need to register for development keys, but there is not cost for that. You will have to register separately for access to the development push servers, again not cost. The production servers are available in free and paid levels depending on the amount of data and service specifics you need.

Comment: d0nparalias Now that the question is open again, and seems popular, perhaps you could invest some time putting together an answer out of what @vcsjones and I have said, and what you have learned. Then accept the answer so the question is complete.

Comment: you are completely right and that was what i was thinking to do. I am thinking though to change the title and also add android and iOS on it , so we have a complete answer on the subject (at least for the major mobile software). what do you think ?

Comment: @Richard , i dont own a blackberry atm. Do you know if i can test push on the simulator?

Comment: For BBOS 7.1 and below if you have a BES/BES Express server you can activate the simulator on the BES and push that way. I don't think you can push to the simulator using BlackBerry infrastructure (BIS). BB10 may be a different story since BB10 does not use BIS push may be implemented differently, I haven't investigated push on BB10 yet.

Answer (score -1):

For WP and Win8, you need a developer license to "side load" apps, meaning they can run on the licensed machine without having to acquire them from the store. See here [Do you need a license to develop a windows phone and blackberry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207998/do-you-need-a-license-to-develop-a-windows-phone-and-blackberry-application)

You also need to register your phone to side load and run apps on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UsingtheWindowsPhoneDeveloperRegistrationTool

You do not pay for these licenses. They are only mechanisms that allows code to execute without going through the store to get the app.

Comment: The Windows Phone registration tool requires an active Developer subscription ($99/yr), so it's definitely not free!

Comment: Not sure when Microsoft updated it, but I just registered my Windows phone using the registration tool for free.